# Get Season in php by user location northern or southern hemisphere

Tags: php, date

I can get the season through the comparison of date, but how can i handle that depends on the user location, if the user location is in the northern or southern hemisphere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830351/is-there-an-easy-way-to-determine-which-hemisphere-a-user-is-in

Comment: This is very extensive  - http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html

Comment: thanks, i'm reading both links

Comment: that is in javascript

Comment: The safest way to get that information is getting it from the client so it involves some client side code (for example javascript like in the links given by Skarlinski) an alternate way would to determine the users location based on his IP, but as you can guess this one is less reliable.

Comment: @Skarlinski This is not a duplicate, for the simple reason that this is tagged `php`. The answer may *be* Javascript, but it's a PHP question.

Comment: *Warning Joke Ahead* `if (confirm('Does your toilet flush clockwise?')) {
  alert("You're in the Northern hemisphere");;
} else {
  alert("You're in the Southern hemisphere");
}

Comment: @lonesomeday Does putting only a link to a stack question has an extra meaning of me saying it's a duplicate? I'm pretty new here, still don't know  all the subtexts.