# Is there an easy PHP way to determine which hemisphere a user is in?

Tags: php, function, location

I'm looking for a way to determine what is the hemisphere of a user who is visiting a web page by using PHP code.

This question is similar to [this JS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830351/is-there-an-easy-way-to-determine-which-hemisphere-a-user-is-in) but using PHP.

Comment: [This](https://javascript.tutorialink.com/is-there-an-easy-way-to-determine-which-hemisphere-a-user-is-in/) may help

Comment: For what it's worth, the server doesn't know what the user time zone is. That's why many sites just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864552/1427345

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));

list($lat, $long) = explode(',', $details->loc);

if ($lat > 0)
    echo 'Northern Hemisphere';
else
    echo 'Southern Hemisphere';
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the hemisphere info without using third party services?

Comment: Yes you would need to download a free GeoIP database and then reference that instead of calling the 3rd party service.

Comment: And is it possible to get the hemisphere info simply based on the client data sent along with his/her browser e.g. datetime, etc.?

Comment: I don't believe so, in PHP we have the variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']`, but it is the time on the server. In HTTP connections, the client does not send it's timestamp to the server.

Comment: You could combine JS and PHP, and pass the client's time through an AJAX request, but then you may as well do it all in JS.

Comment: OK. The JS code in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65658594/502052) could be correct to get the hemisphere info?

Comment: Give it a go. I don't know for sure as I don't have a VM with a GUI in the northern hemisphere to test.